# What type of standard for HPLC capsaicin quantification?

Tags: analytical-chemistry

I'm wondering which type of standard would be the most suitable for the quantitative analysis of capsaicin (8-Methyl-N-vanillyl-trans-6-nonenamide) containing products?

Sigma offers the following types:

- analytical standard
- United States Pharmacopeia reference standard
- European Pharmacopoeia reference standard
- Pharmaceutical secondary standard

While analytic standard entry gives a description (analytical standard for food analysis), assay (99.0+%) and HPLC suitability, no such data is displayed at the product pages of other type of standards.

Regarding my questions let's assume two separate situation here:

a) funds are unlimited
b) funds are limiteted